# typeORM | how to create a many to many relation with repository instead of EntityManager

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have a many to many relation between `users` and `stores`
I have two problems here

1- there is no working example of how to create the relation using the repository

2- using EntityManager works, but I have to fetch the corresponding user before inserting the store, can we do this just by `user.id`?

**Method1: using Repository**

```
let storesRepository = dataSource.manager.getRepository('stores');
let usersRepository = ...

let user = await usersRepository.findOne(...)
let data = req.body
data.users=[user] //or may be data.users=[1,2,3]


// stores are created, but users_stores doesn't created
storesRepository.insert(data);
```

**method2: using EntityManager**

```
let store = new Store();
let user = await usersRepository.findOne(...)

// this works, but why we don't just use the user's Id
// that is received with the request params instead of making a db call to fetch the users?
store.users=[user]
store.otherProps="something"
datasource.manager.save(store)
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution**
1- use `.save()` instead of `insert()`
2- use `{user: {id: '...'}` instead of `{user: 'id'}`

so, the full code is:

```
let storesRepository = dataSource.manager.getRepository('stores');
let usersRepository = ...

// this query is no longer needed
// let user = await usersRepository.findOne(...)
let data = req.body
data.users=[{id: 1}]


// instead of.insert()
storesRepository.save(data);
```